# Breeze is making request to get metadata from server even if we import metadata at client-side

Tags: breeze

We are setting breeze metadata via metadataStore and we were using this approach for months now. But the other day we realized even if we use metadataStore to set metadata, breeze makes a request to server to get metadata-it was not making this request a few versions back (I'm not sure which version, but I can trace back). 
I coded a T4 template to generate a slightly modified metadata, but breeze doesn't use this, always loads metadata from server and overrides mine.

Here how we set our metadata;

```
var core = breeze.core,
    entityModel = breeze.entityModel,
    serviceName = 'api/Service',
    metadataStore = new entityModel.MetadataStore();

metadataStore.importMetadata($.toJSON(metadata));

var createManager = function () {
    return new entityModel.EntityManager({
        serviceName: serviceName,
        metadataStore: metadataStore
    });
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a DataService with 'hasServerMetadata' set to false:

```
    var dataService = new DataService({
         serviceName: serviceName,
         hasServerMetadata: false
     });


     return new EntityManager({
         dataService: dataService,
         metadataStore: metadataStore
     });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Jay, it worked. But now my objects are not converted to observables, is it normal?

Comment: Yes, any results returned from the server that are identified as 'entities' are made observable according to the model library that you have initialized. i.e. knockout, backbone, angular etc. Any objects returned from the server for which no metadata exists are left in their original state.

Comment: OK, so even if we load metadata from a javascript variable to the metadataStore, breeze needs to load metadata from server to track entities?

Comment: Could you mark this as completed when you get the chance, providing you feel that your issue is resolved.  Otherwise this item stays in my "to be reviewed" queue forever. Thx